# Distribute processing of records of scheduler job

Tags: parallel-processing, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, distributed-computing

I am working on a use case where I have a cron job scheduled (via quartz) which reads certain entries from db and process them.
Now in each schedule, I can get thousands of records which need to be processed. Processing each record takes time (in seconds/minutes). Currently all those records are getting processed on single node (node elected by quartz). Now my challenge is to parallelize these records processing. Please help me in solving below concerns :

1. How I can distribute these records/tasks to a cluster of machines
2. If any machine fails after processing few records then remaining records should be processed by healthy nodes in cluster
3. Get a signal that all record processing is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Create cron jobs to run separately on each host at the desired frequency. You will need some form of lock on each record or some form of range lock on the record set to ensure that servers process mutually exclusive set of records.

e.g. : You can add following new field to all records:

Locked By Server:
Locked for Duration (or lock expiration time):

On each run, each cron picks a set of records that have expired or empty locks and then it aquires the lock on a small set of records by putting these two entries. Then it proceeds to process them. If it crashes or gets stuck the lock expires, otherwise it is released on completion.